# Ajax div refresh (without fading in and out)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So i have looked around and most of the code for this looks needlessly beefy. I am looking for **lightweight** ajax code that refreshes a div with an action like:

```
load('boo.php')
```

And I need it to load first on the page opening (ie no delay) then every x seconds refresh (without fade) so you cannot notice a change unless my Database rows have updated but I can do the db bit.

I think i would need something like:

```
onreadystatechange
```

to load when the page loads? Eh im not too sure on this :( any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally recommend using some library for cross-browser support and tested code, e.g. jQuery.

With jQuery, it's as simple as

```
$.get('boo.php', function(data){$('#divId').html(data);});
```

You can wrap this in a function and call it on document ready, then use `setInterval` as suggested by @M1K1O

**Update**
To run the code when the DOM is loaded, the [jQuery API documentation for ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) states that

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - $(document).ready(handler)
> - $().ready(handler) (this is not
>     recommended)
> - $(handler)

Here is a complete example:

```
function refreshDiv()
{
    $.get('boo.php', function(data){$('#divId').html(data);});
}
$(function()
{
    refreshDiv();
    setInterval(refreshDiv, x * 1000); // x is the number of seconds
});
```

Comment: The code worked thanks! Im very new to jQuery, i have had a look on the net and im not sure how making functions works exactly like where their names are defined and how the .onReady thing works :s

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;
var timer = null;
function progressBar(){
if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
    return;
}
timer = window.setInterval(function(){
load('boo.php');
}, 10);
}
window.onload = function() {
progressBar();
};
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Do you use some libries like Jquery ?
Here is some code on jquery for.

```
function update() 
{
  $.get(<URI>,{check:1},function(data){
        $('#div').html(data);
   });    

  setTimeout('update()',1500);
}

$(function(){

   update(); 
});
```

Comment: Do i need <script> tags with this?

Comment: If you are in html then <script type="text/javascript"> <CODE> </script> .
If it's a js file you don't need tags.